# Prolog Connect to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, prolog, connection, ffi

Hi everyone I am developing an expert system for our thesis. But the problem is that i don't know where to start. My professor suggested to make Prolog as my back end and use another language for the user interface. I am planning to use vb.net for the front end, is it possible that vb.net can connect to Prolog.
please help.

Comment: the UI can easily be prototyped in Prolog, don't worry too early about the lower level details...

Answer (score 2):

You can use C# interface for SWI-Prolog written by Uwe Lesta :

- Test cases are running against SWI-Prolog version 6.6.5.
- Sources are available on https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs
- binaries on http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/download/index.htm
- Hopefully completely Unicode capable (Thanks to wchars functions).
- A lot of code cleanup.
- Libpl is an internal class now.

It works also with F# so I think it will work with VB.Net

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you find a .Net based prolog language version then your issue is automatically solved for reason of the common language runtime. It will produce the same IL weither you build the back end from Prolog or from any other .Net language. Therefore you can call your back end produced dlls from any other .Net based front end technology.

I have looked up some .Net based prolog languages and found out:

1. Prolog .Net [here](https://prolog.codeplex.com/) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prolog.NET/)
2. P# [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/research/Psharp/)
3. tutProlog which offers a .Net based version [here](http://apice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/)
4. Planet: a research .Net based prolog project [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.211.5398&rep=rep1&type=pdf)